# how to verify the validity of the binary using the public key?

Tags: cygwin

I want to install Cygwin-64 ,when i go to download page ,some information tells me:
Run setup-x86_64.exe any time you want to update or install a Cygwin package for 64-bit windows. The signature for setup-x86_64.exe can be used to verify the validity of this binary using this public key.

[Installing and Updating Cygwin Packages](https://cygwin.com/install.html)

How can i verify  the validity of this binary using this public key?How to write the command in cmd ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, [import the key](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x56.html#AEN83) with:

```
gpg --import pubring.asc
gpg --list-keys
```

Now you can [verify this signature](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html#AEN160) against your list of public keys:

```
gpg --verify setup-x86_64.exe.sig setup-x86_64.exe
```

Comment: please explain thte answer and what the commands do

Comment: How do you verify the validity of `pubring.asc` found [here](https://cygwin.com/key/pubring.asc)?

Comment: You can alternatively import the public key with `gpg --recv-keys 0xa9a262ff676041ba`. The public key can be found e.g. [here](https://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xA9A262FF676041BA).

Comment: what if I do not have gpg yet? I've found that it is a "chicken and egg problem": https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-05/msg00587.html

Answer (score 0):

`gpg --import pubring.asc` (as in [@elsamuko](https://superuser.com/a/773170/1687279)'s answer) searches for the key in the **hkp://keys.gnupg.net** *keyserver*  (the default in the `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` file). sometimes that server+key combo doesn't seem to work though.

hence, as suggested by [unSpawn](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/unable-to-connect-to-keys-gnupg-net-838576/) and/or [@user1686](https://superuser.com/a/1485255), the alternative is to retrieve the key from a different server... say [http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/](http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=cygwin&fingerprint=on&op=index), for instance. thus:

```
$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 1a698de9e2e56300
$ gpg --list-keys

$ gpg --keyid-format=long --with-fingerprint --verify setup-x86_64.exe.sig setup-x86_64.exe
gpg: Signature made Thu Feb 17 22:01:07 2022 GMT
gpg:                using DSA key A9A262FF676041BA
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
gpg: Signature made Thu Feb 17 22:01:07 2022 GMT
gpg:                using RSA key 1A698DE9E2E56300
gpg: Good signature from "Cygwin <cygwin@cygwin.com>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 5640 5CF6 FCC8 1574 682A  5D56 1A69 8DE9 E2E5 6300
```

... does the trick!.

please follow [this interesting discussion](https://superuser.com/q/1265811/1687279) is you feel icky about the *WARNING* message.